# Not sure how to fix this StackOverflow Exception was Unhandled error

Tags: c#, xna

First time posting here and I know I'll probably get flak for my coding, but I'm a Year 12 student and teaching myself this language for my Software Major, I only just started understanding classes today so I tried to re-do my game with this in-mind, game is far from done. sorry for long post of code but I really can't figure out whats wrong, in the game1.cs is just player.LoadContent(Content), player.Update(gameTime) and player.Draw(spriteBatch), with player being the Object for the Player_Main class.

```
namespace HonourInBlood
{
public class Player_Main //This class deals with updating all other classes
{
    public Player_Sprite psprite = new Player_Sprite();
    public Player_Movement pmove = new Player_Movement();
    public Player_Stats pstats = new Player_Stats();
    public Player_Abilities pabilities = new Player_Abilities();
    public Player_Controls pcontrols = new Player_Controls();

    public Player_Main()
    {

    }
    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        psprite.Update(gameTime);
        pmove.Update(gameTime);
        pstats.Update(gameTime);
        pabilities.Update(gameTime);
    }
    public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
    {
        psprite.LoadContent(Content);
    }
    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        psprite.Draw(spriteBatch);
    }
}

public class Player_Sprite //This class deals with drawing the players sprite and animations
{
    public Rectangle player;
    public Texture2D playerAttack, playerWalk; //PLAYER TEXTURES
    public Player_Main pmain = new Player_Main();

    public Player_Sprite()
    {

    }
    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {

    }
    public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
    {
        player = new Rectangle(0, 0, 64, 64);
        playerAttack = Content.Load<Texture2D>("player_attack_large");
        playerWalk = Content.Load<Texture2D>("player_move_large");
    }
    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(playerWalk, pmain.pmove.position, new Rectangle(0, 0, 64, 64), Color.White);
    }
}

public class Player_Movement //This class deals with all movement relating to the player ie sprinting 
{

    public Vector2 position, velocity, velocity_base, sprint;
    public Player_Main pmain = new Player_Main();
    Game1 gamecore = new Game1();

    public Player_Movement()
    {

    }
    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        KeyboardState KS = Keyboard.GetState();
        //Player movement using arrow keys
        if (KS.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
            position.Y -= velocity.Y;
        if (KS.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
            position.Y += velocity.Y;
        if (KS.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
            position.X += velocity.X;
        if (KS.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
            position.X -= velocity.X;

        //Making edge of screen stop player movement to prevent going off-screen
        if (position.X < 0)
            position.X = 0;
        if (position.Y < 0)
            position.Y = 0;
        if (position.X + pmain.psprite.player.Width > gamecore.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width)
            position.X = gamecore.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width - pmain.psprite.player.Width;
        if (position.Y + pmain.psprite.player.Height > gamecore.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height)
            position.Y = gamecore.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height - pmain.psprite.player.Height;
        //


        //SPRINTING
        if (KS.IsKeyDown(pmain.pcontrols.sprintKey))
        {
            if (KS.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up) || KS.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down) || KS.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right) || KS.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left)) //You're only sprinting when you're moving, right?
            {
                if (pmain.pstats.currentStamina > 0) //Only when you have stamina can you run
                {
                    velocity.X += sprint.X;
                    velocity.Y += sprint.X;
                    pmain.pstats.currentStamina -= pmain.pstats.stamina; //Decreases stamina
                }
            }
        }
        //
        //
        //SPRINTING

        if (pmain.pstats.currentStamina > 0)
        {
            if (velocity.X > velocity_base.X) //When current velocity becomes greater than base velocity check whether space bar is released
            {
                if (KS.IsKeyUp(pmain.pcontrols.sprintKey))
                    velocity.X = velocity_base.X; //If it is, set current velocity back to base
            }

            if (velocity.Y > velocity_base.Y)
            {
                if (KS.IsKeyUp(pmain.pcontrols.sprintKey))
                    velocity.Y = velocity_base.Y;
            }

            if (velocity.X > velocity_base.X + sprint.X)
                velocity.X = velocity_base.X + sprint.X;

            if (velocity.Y > velocity_base.Y + sprint.Y)
                velocity.Y = velocity_base.Y + sprint.Y;
            //
        }

        if (pmain.pstats.currentStamina <= 0) //When you run out of stamina, set speed to normal
        {
            velocity.X = velocity_base.X;
            velocity.Y = velocity_base.Y;
            pmain.pstats.currentStamina = 0;
        }

    }
    public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
    {
        position = new Vector2(400, 300);
        velocity = new Vector2(4, 4); //Current velocity
        velocity_base = new Vector2(4, 4); //Base velocity
        sprint = new Vector2(6, 6); //Added velocity when sprinting
    }
    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {

    }
}

public class Player_Stats //This class deals with all stats of the player
{

    public double stamina, maxStamina, currentStamina, staminaRate, staminaDisplay;
    public double mana, maxMana, currentMana, manaRate, manaDisplay;

    public Player_Stats()
    {

        //STAMINA
        maxStamina = 100f;
        stamina = 1f;
        currentStamina = maxStamina;
        staminaRate = 0.1f;
        staminaDisplay = maxStamina;
        //
        //MANA
        maxMana = 200f;
        mana = 0.5f;
        currentMana = maxMana;
        manaRate = 0.5f;
        manaDisplay = maxMana;
        //
    }
    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        currentStamina += staminaRate; //Stamina regen
        currentMana += manaRate; //TEST STATEMENT

        if (currentStamina > maxStamina) //Cant have more stamina than the max now, can we?
            currentStamina = maxStamina;
        if (currentMana > maxMana)
            currentMana = maxMana;
    }
    public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
    {

    }
    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {

    }
}

public class Player_Abilities //This class deals with all abilities the player has
{
    public double spellCD1, spell1Cost, spellDisplay1;
    Player_Controls pcontrols = new Player_Controls();
    Player_Stats pstats = new Player_Stats();
    Player_Movement pmove = new Player_Movement();
    HUD HUDmain = new HUD();

    public Player_Abilities()
    {
        spellCD1 = 150;
        spell1Cost = 120;
    }
    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        KeyboardState KS = Keyboard.GetState();

        //MANA AND SPELL STUFF///////////////////////////////
        if (KS.IsKeyDown(pcontrols.spellKey1))
        {
            if (pstats.currentMana >= spell1Cost)
            {
                if (spellCD1 <= 0)
                {
                    if (KS.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
                        pmove.position.Y -= 300;
                    if (KS.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
                        pmove.position.Y += 300;
                    if (KS.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
                        pmove.position.X += 300;
                    if (KS.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
                        pmove.position.X -= 300;

                    pstats.mana = spell1Cost;
                    pstats.currentMana -= pstats.mana;
                    spellCD1 = 150;
                }
            }

        }

        spellCD1--;
        spellDisplay1 = spellCD1 / 60;
        spellDisplay1 = Math.Round(spellDisplay1, 1);

        if (spellCD1 <= 0)
            spellCD1 = 0;

    }
    public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
    {

    }
    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.DrawString(HUDmain.HUDFont, "Ability: Cooldown", new Vector2(20, 40), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(HUDmain.HUDFont, "Teleport: " + spellDisplay1 + "s", new Vector2(20, 60), Color.White);
    }
}

public class Player_Controls //This class deals with the controls
{
    public Keys sprintKey, spellKey1;

    public Player_Controls()
    {
        sprintKey = Keys.LeftShift;
        spellKey1 = Keys.D1;

    }
    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {

    }
    public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Here is the call stack:

> HonourInBlood.exe!HonourInBlood.Player_Sprite.Player_Sprite() Line 45 + 0xffffffe6 bytes    C#
>       HonourInBlood.exe!HonourInBlood.Player_Main.Player_Main() Line 14 + 0x15 bytes  C#
>       HonourInBlood.exe!HonourInBlood.Player_Sprite.Player_Sprite() Line 45 + 0x15 bytes  C#
>       HonourInBlood.exe!HonourInBlood.Player_Main.Player_Main() Line 14 + 0x15 bytes  C#
>       HonourInBlood.exe!HonourInBlood.Player_Sprite.Player_Sprite() Line 45 + 0x15 bytes  C#
>       HonourInBlood.exe!HonourInBlood.Player_Main.Player_Main() Line 14 + 0x15 bytes  C#
>       HonourInBlood.exe!HonourInBlood.Player_Sprite.Player_Sprite() Line 45 + 0x15 bytes  C#

It repeats in this fashion until:

```
The maximum number of stack frames supported by Visual Studio has been exceeded.
```

Here is the new question(for Chris Ballard):

After changing the code in all the places I had too, I'm just more confused than before, I have a HUD.cs file that references the Player_Stats class in the Player.cs file for variables but I can't because:

```
'HonourInBlood.Player_Stats' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments
```

If you skim through the code looking at the beginning of each class you can see there is just a web of references that now cause problems since I changed it to the way you showed me.

Comment: Don't worry too much about the long post, BUT we need a clue as to where it is going wrong. When you get the exception, you should be able to see a long stack trace - if you can copy that and edit your question to include it - that will help people a lot.

Comment: Where might I find the long stack trace in visual studio 2010?
EDIT: Nvm I think I found it.

Comment: When the exception happens, assuming you are running in debugger, it will highlight the line on which the exception happened. I don't have VS 2010 to hand (using 2013) but I don't think this has changed - there should be a grey `Exception Helper` window - and this has a `Copy exception detail to clipboard` option. If this window doesn't appear, there might be a red underline on the highlighted line of code - mouse over that and an option to open the exception helper should appear

Comment: I added it to the main question, I think that's what you're asking for?

Comment: added another answer for your second question, which also adjusts the first question

Answer (score 3):

OK - I see the problem.

Everytime you create a `Player_Main` - it has a field which creates a new `Player_Sprite`

**but**

`Player_Sprite` itself has a field which creates another new `Player_Main`,

this in turn creates a new `Player_Sprite` etc, forever (or at least until your stack overflows)

**EDIT**

I'm guessing you want ONE `Player_Main` which retains a reference to `Player_Sprite` and that `Player_Sprite` needs to remember the `Player_Main` which created it (not create a new one). Something like:

```
public class Player_Main 
{
    public Player_Sprite psprite;

    public Player_Main()
    {
        psprite = new Player_Sprite(this);
    }
}

public class Player_Sprite 
{
    public Player_Main _pmain;

    public Player_Sprite(Player_Main pmain)
    {
        _pmain = pmain;
    }
}
```

Comment: How could I fix this? I'm incredibly novice with this language currently.

Comment: Edited with a guess as to what you are really intending

Comment: Could you explain what the parameters (Player_Main pmain) and (this) are for?

Comment: Sure, so you create a player main (one single object) - it creates a player sprite, and passes a reference to itself (`this`) into the constructor for player sprite. Player sprite (I'm guessing) doesn't really want to create a _new_ player main, it just wants to know about the one which created it, hence this is passed in when it is constructed (the `Player_Main` constructor parameter)

Comment: Well the Player_Main class I created just as basically a "holder" class where it would essentially update the other classes in it's update function and loadcontent and draw, and then I only create one object for this class in Game1 and when I call it's update in game1, it updates every class.

Comment: I'm certain the above is what you want. You just have one player_main, which knows about the sprite, movements, etc.

Comment: Okay well thank you, I'll try to fix this problem (I've done similar things in multiple other classes). Really appreciate the help! (since I've done it in the main class with every other class [the whole = new thing] should I change all of them too? Or just the ones that reference back to the main?)

Comment: No problem. Keep at it, it will "click" eventually and then it all becomes obvious, I promise!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the second question. I suspect you have updated `Player_Stats` class to take in `Player_Main` in the constructor.

For `Player_Stats` this isn't necessary. That is because none of the code in `Player_Stats` *needs* to access methods or properties of `Player_Main`. The same is true of `Player_Controls`, `Player_Abilities` and `Player_Movements`

It is only needed in `Player_Sprite` because the `Draw` method accesses `pmain.pmove.position`

As I write this, it comes to mind that perhaps a better implementation would simply to be to pass the position into the `Draw` method, so:

```
public class Player_Sprite //This class deals with drawing the players sprite and animations
{
    public Rectangle player;
    public Texture2D playerAttack, playerWalk; //PLAYER TEXTURES

    public Player_Sprite()
    {

    }

    // .. methods removed for brevity

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Player_Movement pmove)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(playerWalk, pmove.position, new Rectangle(0, 0, 64, 64), Color.White);
    }
}
```

So therefore `Player_Main.Draw` becomes:

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    psprite.Draw(spriteBatch, pmove);
}
```

And you no longer have to pass `this` into the `Player_Sprite` constructor.

**EDIT** Revised `Player_Movement`

```
public class Player_Movement //This class deals with all movement relating to the player ie sprinting 
{
    public Vector2 position, velocity, velocity_base, sprint;
    public Player_Main pmain = null;
    Game1 gamecore = new Game1();

    public Player_Movement(Player_Main pmain)
    {
        this.pmain = pmain;
    }
    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        KeyboardState KS = Keyboard.GetState();
        //Player movement using arrow keys
        if (KS.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
            position.Y -= velocity.Y;
        if (KS.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
            position.Y += velocity.Y;
        if (KS.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
            position.X += velocity.X;
        if (KS.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
            position.X -= velocity.X;

        //Making edge of screen stop player movement to prevent going off-screen
        if (position.X < 0)
            position.X = 0;
        if (position.Y < 0)
            position.Y = 0;
        if (position.X + pmain.psprite.player.Width > gamecore.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width)
            position.X = gamecore.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width - pmain.psprite.player.Width;
        if (position.Y + pmain.psprite.player.Height > gamecore.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height)
            position.Y = gamecore.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height - pmain.psprite.player.Height;
        //


        //SPRINTING
        if (KS.IsKeyDown(pmain.pcontrols.sprintKey))
        {
            if (KS.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up) || KS.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down) || KS.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right) || KS.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left)) //You're only sprinting when you're moving, right?
            {
                if (pmain.pstats.currentStamina > 0) //Only when you have stamina can you run
                {
                    velocity.X += sprint.X;
                    velocity.Y += sprint.X;
                    pmain.pstats.currentStamina -= pmain.pstats.stamina; //Decreases stamina
                }
            }
        }
        //
        //
        //SPRINTING

        if (pmain.pstats.currentStamina > 0)
        {
            if (velocity.X > velocity_base.X) //When current velocity becomes greater than base velocity check whether space bar is released
            {
                if (KS.IsKeyUp(pmain.pcontrols.sprintKey))
                    velocity.X = velocity_base.X; //If it is, set current velocity back to base
            }

            if (velocity.Y > velocity_base.Y)
            {
                if (KS.IsKeyUp(pmain.pcontrols.sprintKey))
                    velocity.Y = velocity_base.Y;
            }

            if (velocity.X > velocity_base.X + sprint.X)
                velocity.X = velocity_base.X + sprint.X;

            if (velocity.Y > velocity_base.Y + sprint.Y)
                velocity.Y = velocity_base.Y + sprint.Y;
            //
        }

        if (pmain.pstats.currentStamina <= 0) //When you run out of stamina, set speed to normal
        {
            velocity.X = velocity_base.X;
            velocity.Y = velocity_base.Y;
            pmain.pstats.currentStamina = 0;
        }

    }
    public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
    {
        position = new Vector2(400, 300);
        velocity = new Vector2(4, 4); //Current velocity
        velocity_base = new Vector2(4, 4); //Base velocity
        sprint = new Vector2(6, 6); //Added velocity when sprinting
    }
    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {

    }
}
```

And in your `Player_Main` constructor, do this:

```
public class Player_Main //This class deals with updating all other classes
{
    public Player_Sprite psprite = new Player_Sprite();
    public Player_Movement pmove = null;
    public Player_Stats pstats = new Player_Stats();
    public Player_Abilities pabilities = new Player_Abilities();
    public Player_Controls pcontrols = new Player_Controls();

    public Player_Main()
    {
         pmove = new Player_Movement(this);
    }

    // ... rest removed for brevity
}
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you for this! I understand this a lot better than the other method. Just making classes and .cs files talk to each other confuses me, and no matter how many tutorials I look up it doesn't help. :(

Comment: One last question (very sorry, haha), if you look at PlayerMovement it also requires the calling of Player_Main, and this results in a stackoverflow, how would I go about fixing this? (Should be my last question as I can use this to fix all the others)

Comment: This is actually much more canonical object oriented code. Usually you don't want to have two classes each keeping references to each other, as you get problems (like your original StackOverflow) issue. Wherever possible, you just have a class reference in one direction, like we now have: `Player_Main` knows about `Player_Sprite` but `Player_Sprite` doesn't know about `Player_Main`

Comment: OK, hang on Ill check

Comment: OK, as it stands, `Player_Movement` does need the pattern I mentioned in my previous answer. It is created by `Player_Main`, which passes a reference to itself into the constructor. `Player_Movement` should not create a **new** `Player_Main` (as it currently does), rather in its constructor, it stores the passed in reference to `Player_Main` in an existing field.

Comment: Would you be able to edit the answer above adding in sample code as to what you mean? I find it easier to understand when I read the code as well. :P